# How do I force a defrost cycle on my refrigerator?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, refrigerator

My Kenmore 596.51679100 side by side fridge is tripping the dedicated GFCI circuit in my garage that it's plugged into and I suspect it's the defrost heater but I need to test this. As far as I can tell this model has no timer, but a thermostat and a control board. How can I force a defrost cycle to run?

Edit: This is in a garage, so all outlets are, by code, GFCI protected.

Comment: Nuisance trips like this are the reason it's recommended that refrigerators _not_ be plugged into GFCI protected outlets. It would suck to leave for a long weekend only to return to a fridge full of spoiled food because it decided to defrost, tripped the breaker, and slowly got warm while you were gone.

Comment: Everything I read says it's code now for appliances in garages to be GFCI protected (in fact all garage outlets should be), and that outlet is specifically designated for a freezer/fridge, so it's on an independent circuit. And this is a beer fridge, so I'm not worried about spoilage.

Comment: Ah. I see you've edited that into your post now. Good to try to remember to include things like that up front to avoid confusion from potential answerers. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: After doing some reading, it seems that best approach is to replace the GFCI outlet with a normal 20a outlet. This doesn't meet the code perfectly. However, the outlet is on a dedicated 20a circuit, in the back of garage, 4ft off the ground, and not readily accessible, so given those circumstances it seems that it's fairly normal, and safe to use a normal outlet.